# Serializable classes with subclasses

Tags: kotlin, serialization, dataclasses

I'm trying to build a selector in my main method:

```
fun main() {
    val gen = TestGenerator()
    val testSet = listOf(
        TestSpec("Test-1", SCENARIO, when (ALGORITHM) {
            AlgorithmType.MAXPLUS -> MaxPlusSpec(MIN_REWARD, MAX_REWARD, MAX_ITER, THRESHOLD, COMPUTATION_TYPE)
            AlgorithmType.MCTS -> MCTSSpec(MIN_REWARD, MAX_REWARD, MAX_ITER, C_VALUE, COMPUTATION_TYPE)
        })
    )
    gen.runLinearTestSet(testSet)
}
```

So, when either maxplus or mcts is selected with either centralized or decentralized computation, we want to pass the right parameters according to it.

I tried solving it like this:

```
@Serializable
data class MaxPlusSpec(
    val minReward: Float,
    val maxReward: Float,
    val maxIterationNumber: Int,
    val convergenceThreshold: Float,
    computationType: ComputationType
) : AlgorithmSpec(AlgorithmType.MAXPLUS, computationType)

@Serializable
data class MCTSSpec(
    val minReward: Float,
    val maxReward: Float,
    val maxIterationNumber: Int,
    val cValue: Float,
    computationType: ComputationType
) : AlgorithmSpec(AlgorithmType.MCTS, computationType)
```

Which throws errors:

> 'computationType' hides member of supertype 'AlgorithmSpec' and needs 'override' modifier

> Serializable class has duplicate serial name of property 'computationType', either in the class itself or its supertypes

So I tried implementing it like this:

```
@Serializable
data class MaxPlusSpec(
    val minReward: Float,
    val maxReward: Float,
    val maxIterationNumber: Int,
    val convergenceThreshold: Float,
    computationType: ComputationType
) : AlgorithmSpec(AlgorithmType.MAXPLUS, computationType)

@Serializable
data class MCTSSpec(
    val minReward: Float,
    val maxReward: Float,
    val maxIterationNumber: Int,
    val cValue: Float,
    computationType: ComputationType
) : AlgorithmSpec(AlgorithmType.MCTS, computationType)
```

Which of course does not work because we can not assign computationtype without var/val keyword in data class.

I don't know how to make this work. Any help would be much appreciated.

Edit:

Currently went with this workaround, which isn't optimal but does work for now:

```
    @Serializable
abstract class AlgorithmSpec(
    val algorithmType: AlgorithmType
) {
    abstract val computationType: ComputationType
}

@Serializable
data class MaxPlusSpec(
    val minReward: Float,
    val maxReward: Float,
    val maxIterationNumber: Int,
    val convergenceThreshold: Float,
    override val computationType: ComputationType
) : AlgorithmSpec(AlgorithmType.MAXPLUS)

@Serializable
data class MCTSSpec(
    val minReward: Float,
    val maxReward: Float,
    val maxIterationNumber: Int,
    val cValue: Float,
    override val computationType: ComputationType
) : AlgorithmSpec(AlgorithmType.MCTS)
```

Comment: Why not declare `computationType` as "`override val`"?

Comment: Because computationType is final and therefore cannot be overridden. I also can‘t declare computationType as abstract as it‘s the primary constructor.

Comment: I think your solution is fine. I'm not sure why you don't like it. You can also give computationType a different name in the child class, and/or write a custom serializer if necessary. Lots of options.

Comment: The abstract class did not work with the serialization correctly. I changed it to a sealed class, now everything works correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved as follows:

```
@Serializable
sealed class AlgorithmSpec(
    val algorithmType: AlgorithmType
) {
    abstract val computationType: ComputationType
}

@Serializable
data class MaxPlusSpec(
    val minReward: Float,
    val maxReward: Float,
    val maxIterationNumber: Int,
    val convergenceThreshold: Float,
    override val computationType: ComputationType
) : AlgorithmSpec(AlgorithmType.MAXPLUS)

@Serializable
data class MCTSSpec(
    val minReward: Float,
    val maxReward: Float,
    val maxIterationNumber: Int,
    val cValue: Float,
    override val computationType: ComputationType
) : AlgorithmSpec(AlgorithmType.MCTS)
```